# Route data not accessible in template

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a problem accessing the data from an route.

#### Router

```js
Router.route('/view/:_id', {
    name: 'locationView',
    data: function() { return Locations.findOne(this.params._id); }
});
```

`Locations` is a MongoDB Collection that i've subscribed to. I can access it via a helper method on another template without problems. It has objects like name, address etc.

#### Template

```html
<template name="locationView">
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>
</template>
```

#### Demo

[Application hosted on meteor.com](http://mhaehnel-compass.meteor.com/)

On the front-page you can see that the entries from Locations are accessible from other templates over helper methods. So why i can't access them via the data object from the route?

---

## Solution

The problem was adding the objects via mongo shell. That caused the ObjectID(xxx) stuff to appear in the _id of the object.

I've added some test objects via collection method 'insert' and everything works fine!

Comment: Where did you put the subscription to your Locations?

Comment: @BraveKenny It's in a js file in the client folder. The publication is in the server folder. But this isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

The problem was adding the objects via mongo shell. That caused the ObjectID(xxx) stuff to appear in the _id of the object.

I've added some test objects via collection method 'insert' and everything works fine!

Answer (score 1):

I just tried you application and i saw this url:

http://mhaehnel-compass.meteor.com/view/ObjectID(%22554e58c15eb2cd41fc085c0e%22)

The ObjectID() part is just for mongodb and is not supposed to be in you url.. that's why meteor is not doing the thing you expected. This could be an example how you would set your link to the locationView route

{{pathFor 'locationView' _id = this._id}}

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The `data` defined in your route is stored in your template instance, ergo `Template.instance().data`. You can also access it in `onRendered` using simply `this.data`:

```
Template.locationView.onRendered(function () {
  var data = this.data;
});
```

Comment: How would this me an solution for his problem? Apparently the data context is not getting filled with the right data. If the data is not available in the context it is neither in the on rendered callback or am I missing something?

Comment: Well the question was: "how can he access the data object from the route".

Comment: WOops, ur completely right! Probably to much coffee ;p

Comment: But your concern is valid, I would also be more worried about those `ObjectID()` in the links if I were OP. But I figured hey, maybe he's still just in building process and wants to tackle this issue afterwards.

Comment: I know what the problem is. Locations i added over the mongoshell have the ObjectID in it's _id field. If i add them over the Meteor insert function everything works fine! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, Meteor does not use ObjectIDs but Strings for documents IDs, therefore it could not find your document there. Dennis's clues were more in the right direction then.